# tex4ht removes spaces in href description in Lua mode when using mathdesign package

Tags: hyperref, tex4ht, mathdesign, make4ht

Any idea why this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %DO NOT USE WIT LUALATEX, only with pdflatex
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\href{foo}{what happened to the spaces between the words}
\end{document}
```

When compiled using `make4ht --lua   foo.tex` produces this HTML

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compiling without `--lua` produces this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ALso compiling without `mathdesign` but keeping `--lua` produces the above correct result.

So there seems to be a conflict between `lua` and `mathdesign` package?

Is there a way to correct this?  Am I doing something I should not be doing? TL 2015.

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
mathtools.sty    2015/11/12 v1.18 mathematical typesetting tools
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 mhsetup.sty    2010/01/21 v1.2a programming setup (MH)
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2015/09/07 v1.1p UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2015/09/07 v1.1p UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2015/09/07 v1.1p UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2015/09/07 v1.1p UTF-8 support for inputenc
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
 ***********
```

Comment: it seems that different fonts are selected by `mathdesign` under `lualatex` and `pdflatex`. I would include `mathdesign` optionally only when `tex4ht` isn't used

Comment: if you are using that document with luatex you shouldn't have `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, or as it says in your comment use inputenc

Answer (score 2):

The strange issue is that different fonts are selected when compiled with pdftex and luatex. I cannot figure out how the selection works from the mathdesign source code, anyway, when I took a look at the DVI code, there is a difference:

pdftex:

```
   set: 'what'
      w: 2.678421pt
      set: 'happened'
      w0:
      set: 'to'
      w0:
      set: 'the'
      w0:
      set: 'spaces'
      w0:
      set: 'between'
      w0:
      set: 'the'
      w0:
      set: 'words'
```

luatex:

```
  set: 'what'
  right: 2.678421pt
  set: 'happened'
  right: 2.678421pt
  set: 'to'
  right: 2.678421pt
  set: 'the'
  right: 2.678421pt
  set: 'spaces'
  right: 2.678421pt
  set: 'between'
  right: 2.678421pt
  set: 'the'
  right: 2.678421pt
  set: 'words'
```

I am not expert on the DVI format, but I guess that font selected by luatex uses kerns instead of spaces. So maybe it is a font isssue? Can anybody confirm that?

Anyway, as the font changing in this case affects only PDF form, in HTML it doesn't matter, I would use conditional compilation and include the `mathdesign` only when the document is compiled with pdflatex:

```
\ifdefined\HCode
\else
   \usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\fi
```